# URL ending with '/Whatever'

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I hope, you can help me with this one.

Is it possible to have an URL like this : http://example.com/xxxyyy
When users access the above link, I'd like to extract the xxxyyy part of the URL for further use.

I'd like to do this WITHOUT subdomains, as I don't know how many different 'xxxyyy's I'll have to accept. (eg http://example.com/europe, http://example.com/spam and so on)

Regards,
Morten

Comment: Can you please supply some code of what you have tried. Maybe include some more information on what framework you're using with asp.net.

Comment: You are looking for [url-rewrite.](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: Is this WebForms (.aspx) or MVC or even something else?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you're trying to do, but you should find what you need here: [Making Sense of ASP.NET Paths](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths)

For example:

```
string path = Request.ApplicationPath;
```

Check the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath(v=vs.110).aspx).